# java.lang.IllegalStateException : No thread-bound request found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a use case where I am trying to generate a token from my token utility ,
Its working fine from one service class but when trying through another its throwing me error
The only difference is this service method is @Async
Note:- I have @autowired the dependency in both the classes
Below is the piece of code snippet which throws error:-

```
     public String getAuthorizationHeader() {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)     RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    if(request != null) {
        return request.getHeader("Authorization");
    } else {
        throw new BadRequestException(ErrorConstants.INVALID_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

I have declared in same way how its present in other class, the only difference is on first instance where I get the result is done some steps ahead like when the method just started and other when I just want to make API call during that period some  business validations happen.

Expected result:- Token should be derived in all use case

Below is complete token class

```
       @Component
      public class JwtTokenUtils {
      private final Logger log = 
  LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtTokenUtils.class);

@Value("${security.jwt.token.secret-key:secret-key}")
private String secretKey;

@PostConstruct
protected void init() {
    secretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getBytes());
}

public String getToken() {
    String authToken = getAuthorizationHeader();
    
    if (authToken != null && authToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        return authToken.substring(7);
    } else {
        throw new BadRequestException(ErrorConstants.INVALID_REQUEST, "No/Invalid Authorization Token Provided");
    }
}

public String getAuthorizationHeader() {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    if(request != null) {
        return request.getHeader("Authorization");
    } else {
        throw new BadRequestException(ErrorConstants.INVALID_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: Though it is hard to point exact issue from the message it is kind of clear that you are trying to access the Security context before it is populated correctly. The security aspect is handled with filters in the spring filter chains. Most likely you are also running your code in another aspect which happening before hand.

Comment: You are using this method, the `RequestContext` outside of an HTTP request, which is ofcourse not going to work.

Comment: @M.Deinum the service method is "Async" from where we are calling the method

Comment: Hence it will not work as there is no request for the background thread.

Comment: Any idea how to handle this @M.Deinum